# MvvmCross.Forms 5.4: How to setup UWP project?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross, xamarin.uwp

I started a new Xamarin project and installed the MvvmCross.Forms.StarterPack 5.4 NuGet. All of the projects were changed to support the MvvmCross framework except for the UWP project. What do I need to add to the UWP project so that it will build and run?

Comment: Have you checked the sample projects in github repo? Basically you need a Setup.cs and some code in MainPage to wire it up

Answer (score 0):

MvvmCross has a playground project setup for UWP, https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/develop/TestProjects/Playground/Playground.Forms.Uwp. Maybe you can follow it to set it up manually.